# GIT how do I know who or which users cloned the repo?

Tags: git, git-clone

I've a private REPO in GIT 1.7 in a Ubuntu Server that is available for a group of users. I would like to know if there is a way to learn which user had already cloned that mentioned REPO. Is there a command to do this ? 
Any help or comment is more than welcome.

Comment: Git is decentralised, so even if you found out who cloned *your* repo, someone may have cloned *his* copy and so on ad infinitum. There is no way to be sure of this with a decentralised system.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This question has been commented to in the other thread, Seems like the architecture concept doesn't allow to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719936/git-repository-cloning-logging

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to check server logs for users who has accessed the repository, git itself does not record anything like this.

However this will give you list of people who did access directly the server, but this is no way definite list of people who have cloned the repository - they can clone from each other without any limitations, that's how distributed version control works.

Comment: ... and that will only tell you who accessed the repository directly. Somebody could have cloned one of the clones.

Comment: Of course, but that's probably best you can achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This question has been commented to in the other thread, Seems like the architecture concept doesn't allow to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719936/git-repository-cloning-logging

Answer (score 0):

Now I user Subversion - but this overall concept seems valid - I'm sure I'll get downvoted by anyone that knows Git but oh well...

if you have a pre-existing group, couldn't you then do a `git clone --reference <repository>`, by doing on check on each group member? One would show up if there was a clone there for that user, no?

Comment: ... except all the users would have to do `--reference` clone and there is nothing forcing them to.

Comment: ahh...tousche ;) I tried...