# GIT : List of people cloned a repo

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to get List of users / people who cloned project from a particular repository?

Comment: Do you mean github specifically?

Comment: On own git server You could collect statistics with external tools.

Comment: This question suggests that you have a workflow that's broken. Can you state why you need this information and how you're using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Next time google first please:

> The only way to do this is to check server logs for users who has
>   accessed the repository, git itself does not record anything like
>   this.
>
> However this will give you list of people who did access directly the
>   server, but this is no way definite list of people who have cloned the
>   repository - they can clone from each other without any limitations,
>   that's how distributed version control works.c

Source: [GIT how do I know who or which users cloned the repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835124/git-how-do-i-know-who-or-which-users-cloned-the-repo)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot know this information on `git` or on `github`.