# How to know local repo is different from remote repo, without fetch?

Tags: git-remote, git-diff, git

I got tens of repos, my script should update them if any difference happened, new commits, new tag, new branch. Fetch is kind of slow for tens of repos in my case, I'd like to know if there is any quick command could meet my requirement.

Comment: Automatic updates are bad for live servers

Comment: Without a `fetch`, your `git` has no knowledge of the state of the remote repositories. Any solution that does not perform a `fetch` (e.g. `diff` against the full remote URL) would be at least as slow as a `fetch`, because it will still need to retrieve the state of the remote repository.

Comment: @Ianzz Certainly you could just look at the remote heads to see if one has changed without actually fetching a pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `git ls-remote` plumbing command to obtain the state of the remotes without fetch.

**Here, let’s use git itself as a lightweight database, to keep track of the state of the remote.**

Put the following in a script; you can enable it later as a git alias shell function for convenience. Run inside your repo.

```
REMOTE_SUM=$(git ls-remote --tags --heads 2>/dev/null | git hash-object --stdin)
if git cat-file -e $REMOTE_SUM
then
    echo Remote check-summed up-to-date.
else
    echo Remote changed, fetching...
    git ls-remote --tags --heads 2>/dev/null | \
        git hash-object -w --stdin &>/dev/null
    git fetch
fi
```

<sub>Some of the necessary error checking was omitted, and code was duplicated for sake of clarity.</sub>

**Explanation**

Listing all the remote tips with `git ls-remote --tags --heads` generates output such as:

```
From /home/user/tmp/repo2
777201715768a4d82f374f7224e68164a916ac1f        refs/heads/bar
78981922613b2afb6025042ff6bd878ac1994e85        refs/heads/master
...
```

In turn we hash the above picture of the remote repo as a single hash via `git hash-object --stdin` and check if we've previously seen it by querying for the hash in git with `git cat-file -e`. If we haven't seen it, the remote picture must have changed, and we record it first in git with `git hash-object -w`, to accommodate races between pulling and committing on the remote, and then proceed to fetch the remote.

One can integrate this with a git pre-fetch functionality: [pre-fetch hook functionality in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243729/), but that's out of the scope of this answer.

**Addendum**

Note that the above will generate loose objects in git that occasionally will need to be garbage collected with `git gc`, and possibly `--prune` explicitly.

Further, the above should work as long as commits are not rearranged on purpose in such a way that branch tips remain the same. This would be /quite uncommon/ and goes against git guidelines of changing pushed state, but hey, the worst thing that can happen is that you skip a fetch.

Also note that `ls-remote` works on a single remote. To work with multiple remotes, you'll have to extend the script by generating a list of remotes with `git remote show` and work with each one in turn.

Comment: Sounds great! If I did a force push to remote, does it work? Not rebase of course.

Comment: Yes a branch name is just a moniker for a tip, ie a top-level commit in a tree of objects. You can see that ls-remote lists these tips, and when you forcefully push the tip will change, the snapshot of the remote will look different, hash to a a different hash value, and thus a full fetch will be run on the first invocation, and then none on subsequent.

Answer (score 2):

## You don't have access to the `origin` server

You can't using only `git`.

**EDIT**

As per another answer, `git ls-remote` may be of use to you.

However, as you would have to `ls-remote` all the repositories, if your problem is a network lag, it won't be solved with `ls-remote`.

---

## You have access to the `origin` server

1. Setup a hook when there is a write on the repo on the server. The hook would mark the repo as being modified. You can for instance create a `repo_name__MODIFIED` file somewhere on the server).
2. Before updating the repo, check if the repo is modified. For the given example, check if the file `repo_name__MODIFIED` exist on the server.
3. If the repo was modified, before updating the repo, mark it as unmodified (just before the fetch). In the case of our example, simply delete the `repo_name__MODIFIED` file on the server.

---

## Note

Why is the fetch so long? `git` will only fetch the new commits, if there are no modifications to the `origin`, it should be very fast!

Comment: Actually my build machine would fetch tens of repos to get latest code, the single fetch was quick, but total time of fetches (network requests) lasted minutes. That was bad, or bad design for build machine

Comment: Okay. So what do you think of my solution? Do you have access to the origin server? If you need more informations, I can develop further.

Comment: I can access to the origin server, I understood your solution, it's worth trying, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your local repositories using `git clone` or `git remote add $REMOTE_NAME $REMOTE_URL`, all the information that you need to compare your local branches to their remote counterparts (at the time of your last `git fetch`) is already there.

If you have set up remote tracking branches, `git status` tells you if about differences to the remote branch you are tracking, like this.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   perl/Makefile.am

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

There's also a parseable form:

```
$ git status --porcelain -b
## master...origin/master [behind 1]
 M perl/Makefile.am
```

Comment: this didn't work for a new tag was pushed by someone elsewhere. git-status works only for current working tree, I think.