# git: how to document that a repo has been shut down?

Tags: git, configuration, repository, transfer

I have an old repo server at `server1.example.com` and I want to transfer all git repositories to `git.example.com`. Does git support configuring `server1.example.com` so that in case anybody still tries to `fetch`, `push` or `clone` their workspace against `server1.example.com`, they would get a custom error message saying "`error: server1.example.com has been shut down, use git.example.com instead`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks): Hooks are scripts that are executed in certain circumstances. You can set up a server-side pre-receive hook, running always when someone tries to push to your repository, that always exits with exit code 1 (and thus will decline every push) and shows the `error: server1.example.com has been shut down, use git.example.com instead` message.

An example (that is probably too sophisticated for your case) can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy).

This will only work for pushes, however. The possibility of something like `clone` hooks is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook), for `fetch` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243729/pre-fetch-hook-functionality-in-git), but there is no git internal funktionality for either one.